# Send message from php to ajax with 'echo json_encode' not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a message from php to ajax. I'm using `echo json_encode` to do it. When I do that, the website displays the `arrays` message. (`{"foo":"content of foo"}`). How can I get it to **not** display the message?

Also, the alerts from ajax don't get called.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$myString = $_POST['data'];

if ($myString == "") {
    echo json_encode(
      array()
      );

} else if ($myString == "foo" {
    echo json_encode(
      array(
        'foo2' => 'this is the contents of foo'
        )
      );
} else if ($myString == "foo2") {
    echo json_encode(
      array(
        'foo2' => 'this is the contents of foo2'
        )
      );
}
?>


<script>
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    context: document.body,
    data: formData, 
    type: "POST",  
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.length == 0) {
          alert("empty");
      } else if (response.foo) {          
          alert("foo");
      } else if (respons.foo2) {
          alert("foo2");
      }          
    }
  });           
</script>
```

How can I get the array to not display on the website? And why are the ajax if statements not getting called?

Comment: Are these on the same page just like this?

Comment: forgot to use `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: @Rasclatt No. 2 separate files

Comment: You have a syntax error on this line-> `else if ($myString == "foo" {`

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer from @gview. But I appreciate it! If it's possible, can you answer my question in the answers comments please?

Comment: So you have it working or not working then?

Comment: I have it working, but @gview said I shouldn't do that, or something.

Comment: No, he was asking the same thing I was asking which is if you have the php and javascript on two separate pages or not. I'm just letting you know that your php has a syntax error, but you must have already fixed it because you said it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the HTTP header at the top of the script so you can return son:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Your script is a little confusing.  You can't return json AND html/javascript.

It's one or the other.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I put that?

Comment: Right at the top of the script, however, it's a bit confusing as to why you are trying to combine some javascript/ajax code with the server side script.  You realize that javascript runs in the browser, right?

Comment: It isn't regular to send a message from php to ajax, then to run javascript code from that message?

Comment: The reason I'm doing that is because I'm not so fluent in php. I'm therefore trying to minimize the php usage. So that's why I want to send the message from php to ajax, then run javascript code.